# How to Check whether the user logged in and Redirect Accordingly

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my Route :

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home');
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@Login');
Route::get('vehicle', 'VehicleController@VehicleLayout');
```

So far all pages can be accessed by any users.

And I started using `auth::user` So

```
    if (Auth::attempt($LoginData))
    {
        return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('')->with('Message', 'UserName or Password Invalid');
    }
```

I am checking in the Login screen.

But from my above code. The page `vehicle` can be accessed from any where. And there i am getting the logged in user's details by `{{ Auth::user()->FirstName}}`

And when i try to access the vehicle page, If the user didn't logged in it simply throws the error

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mti\app\views\layouts\dashboardlayout.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\mti\app\views\layouts\dashboardlayout.blade.php)
```

Is there any way to check whether the user has logged in and Redirect the user to login page with errors in laravel way.

```
<?php
if (Auth::guest())
{
    return Redirect::to('logout')->with('Message', 'You Must Logged In to Access this page.');
}
?>
```

Is the above given a good process or is there any laravel way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can and should use [**filters**](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters) for this. There's even a built in [`auth` filter](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#protecting-routes) (you can find it inside `app/filters.php`)

It works very well in combination with route groups. Here's an example:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::get('vehicle', 'VehicleController@VehicleLayout');
    Route::get('foo', 'FooController@BarAction');
});
```

Comment: So, should i change all the request in routes.php with one with **Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::get('xx', 'xxController@xxLayout');
});**   I mean it will work with all **get** and **post** methods ?

Comment: No you can put all auth protected routes inside the group. I updated my answer...

Comment: It includes all **get** and **post** method ?

Comment: Ahmm, to be clear **Route::get** and **Route::post**

Comment: Yes, routes of any type and HTTP verb put inside that group will be protected. Just try it out and hit me up if something doesn't work ;)

Comment: And, in the filter **if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');** We are returning the user to **/** can i send a custom message to that, like `you must be logged in to accesss` like that

Comment: Got it, Tried myself :)

Answer (score 0):

In laravel it's simple to do what you are asking.

There is a function to check values from login form, and then check if the user exists in database.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array( 'email' => $email, 'password' => $password ) ) )
{

return Redirect::to( 'your route' );     // route for loged users

}else
{

return Redirect::to('/home')->withMessage('Wrong username/pass')

}
```

On the home page you can display error message like this {{  If(Session::has('message') {{ $message}}  }}

If you have that user in database, the function will redirect you to page where loged user go, and then you can type Auth::user()->username, and you will be able to acces any data of that user.

**To check if the user is loged, just type

```
if(Auth::check){
then do something
}else{
do something else
}**
```